# ListView getItem onClick() in Tab Fragment

Tags: listview, android-listview, listviewitem

I currently have 9 tabs which all display different items (using this tutorial http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-custom-listview-texts-and-images-tutorial/). my issue right now is that when I click on the item it doesn't go to my other activity which gives more detail on each item.  I'm assuming it's because of the line `return rootView` at the end, yet I'm not sure what else to do in order to get display the items and the tabs. Here's my code:

```
public class CreatorFirstScreen extends FragmentActivity {

      SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

      ViewPager mViewPager;  

@Override  
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_creatorfirst);  

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three  
    // primary sections of the app.  
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());  

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.  
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);  
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);  

    PagerTabStrip strip = (PagerTabStrip)findViewById(R.id.tabstrip);
    strip.setTabIndicatorColor(0xFFFF);

}    

/** 
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to 
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages. 
 */  
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {  

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {  
        super(fm);  
    }  

    @Override  
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {  
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.  
        // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class  
        // below) with the page number as its lone argument.  
        Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();  
        Bundle args = new Bundle();  
        args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);  
        fragment.setArguments(args);  
        return fragment;  
    }  

    @Override  
    public int getCount() {  
        // Show 9 total pages.  
        return 9;  
    }  

    @Override  
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {  
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();  
        switch (position) {  
        case 0:  
            return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);  
        case 1:  
            return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);  
        case 2:  
            return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);  
        case 3:  
            return getString(R.string.title_section4).toUpperCase(l); 
        case 4:  
            return getString(R.string.title_section5).toUpperCase(l); 
        case 5:  
            return getString(R.string.title_section6).toUpperCase(l); 
        case 6:  
            return getString(R.string.title_section7).toUpperCase(l); 
        case 7:  
            return getString(R.string.title_section8).toUpperCase(l); 
        case 8: 
            return getString(R.string.title_section9).toUpperCase(l);
        }  
        return null;  
    }  
}  

/** 
 * A dummy fragment representing a section of the app, but that simply 
 * displays dummy text. 
 */  
public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {  
    /** 
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this 
     * fragment. 
     */  
    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";  
    private ListView mainListView ;  
 // Declare Variables
    ListView list;
    ListViewAdapter adapter;
    String[] title;
    String[] comment;
    String[] rank;
    int[] picture;

    public DummySectionFragment() {  
    }  

    @Override  
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_dummy, container, false);  


        // Set the ArrayAdapter as the ListView's adapter.  
        switch (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)) {
            case 1:  
                // Generate sample data into string arrays
                rank = new String[] {"1","2"};
                title = new String[] { "China", "India" };
                comment = new String[] { "1,354,040,0002111131241352346262624t246gsdgw4vtwbbtqvtq3v5q3q5tq tq4tq4vrvq3v5q3vq2vq4bqv6w46w4tvw5w54b547be5bryene7bebev7we6q665ebeve", "1,210,193,422" };
                picture = new int[] { R.drawable.china, R.drawable.india }; 
                break;
            case 2:
                // Generate sample data into string arrays
                rank = new String[] {"1","2"};
                title = new String[] { "United States", "Indonesia"};  
                comment = new String[] {"315,761,000", "237,641,326"};
                picture = new int[] { R.drawable.unitedstates, R.drawable.indonesia };
                break;
            case 3:
                // Generate sample data into string arrays
                rank = new String[] {"1","2"};
                title = new String[] { "China", "India" };
                comment = new String[] { "1,354,040,000", "1,210,193,422" };
                picture = new int[] { R.drawable.china, R.drawable.india }; 
                break;
            case 4:
                // Generate sample data into string arrays
                rank = new String[] {"1","2"};
                title = new String[] { "China", "India" };
                comment = new String[] { "1,354,040,000", "1,210,193,422" };
                picture = new int[] { R.drawable.china, R.drawable.india }; 
                break;
            case 5:
                // Generate sample data into string arrays
                rank = new String[] {"1","2"};
                title = new String[] { "China", "India" };
                comment = new String[] { "1,354,040,000", "1,210,193,422" };
                picture = new int[] { R.drawable.china, R.drawable.india }; 
                break;
            case 6:
                // Generate sample data into string arrays
                rank = new String[] {"1","2"};
                title = new String[] { "China", "India" };
                comment = new String[] { "1,354,040,000", "1,210,193,422" };
                picture = new int[] { R.drawable.china, R.drawable.india }; 
                break;
            case 7:
                // Generate sample data into string arrays
                rank = new String[] {"1","2"};
                title = new String[] { "China", "India" };
                comment = new String[] { "1,354,040,000", "1,210,193,422" };
                picture = new int[] { R.drawable.china, R.drawable.india }; 
                break;
            case 8:
                // Generate sample data into string arrays
                rank = new String[] {"1","2"};
                title = new String[] { "China", "India" };
                comment = new String[] { "1,354,040,000", "1,210,193,422" };
                picture = new int[] { R.drawable.china, R.drawable.india }; 
                break;
            case 9:
                // Generate sample data into string arrays
                rank = new String[] {"1","2"};
                title = new String[] { "China", "India" };
                comment = new String[] { "1,354,040,000", "1,210,193,422" };
                picture = new int[] { R.drawable.china, R.drawable.india }; 
        }

        // Locate the ListView in listview_main.xml
        mainListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);

        // Pass results to ListViewAdapter Class
        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(getActivity(), rank, title, comment, picture);
        // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
        mainListView.setAdapter(adapter);
        // Capture ListView item click
        mainListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), SingleItemView.class);
                // Pass all data rank
                i.putExtra("rank", rank);
                // Pass all data country
                i.putExtra("title", title);
                // Pass all data population
                i.putExtra("comment", comment);
                // Pass all data flag
                i.putExtra("picture", picture);
                // Pass a single position
                i.putExtra("position", position);
                // Open SingleItemView.java Activity
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        return rootView;  
    }  
}  

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>I believe the `OnItemClickListener` doesn't get attached to the `mainListView` because its root view hasn't yet been created. For it to work, try moving the related code (everything after the switch statement) to the [`onViewCreated`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onViewCreated%28android.view.View,%20android.os.Bundle%29) method which fires right after `onCreateView` returns the `rootView`.</del>

A `CheckBox` that's present in this `ListView`'s row layout will steal its parent view's focus so the `OnItemClickListener`'s `onItemClick` method won't get called. To overcome this, add `android:focusable="false"`
and `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` parameters to the `CheckBox`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @Slavko.  Unfortunately, that's still not helping me out.  I need to have the following 3 lines still in onCreateView to get the list items to show:

`mainListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
adapter = new ListViewAdapter(getActivity(), rank, title, comment, picture);
mainListView.setAdapter(adapter);`

Not sure how to get the items in mainListView.  Any more help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I've tried creating a FragmentActivity using your code and some simple layouts, and everything seems to work without doing what I proposed. What happens when you click a ListView item? Nothing at all or an exception gets thrown?

Comment: nothing at all :( i looked to see if it posts anything too but nothing.  did you have to create a onViewCreated method?

Comment: Nope, I've just renamed a few things. Are you sure there's a ListView with an id of "listView" in your fragment_main_dummy.xml?

Comment: yes. my fragment_main_dummy.xml looks looks like this: 

`<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".CreatorFirstScreen$DummySectionFragment" >
 
 <ListView 
     android:id="@+id/listView"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
 
</RelativeLayout>`

Comment: `<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="90sp" >
  
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30sp"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
 
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/comment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60sp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="2"`

Comment: `android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/itemCheckBox"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title" />
 
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/itemCheckBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/picture"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>`

Comment: `<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/picture"
        android:layout_width="85sp"
        android:layout_height="85sp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="#ffff"
        android:padding="1dp" />
</RelativeLayout>`

Comment: Try adding android:focusable="false" and android:focusableInTouchMode="false" to your CheckBox item and let me know if that helped.

Comment: man you are awesome!! thank that made it work.  not sure why that was the problem but i'll read up on it.

Comment: Great! We've both learned something new today. :) I'll update the answer so you could accept it.